# How to know when an object's status is changed?

Tags: android

I have a quick question. I would like achieve this:

```
If(any player field has changed)
{
UpdateTextView()
}else
{
Wait for any change
}
```

In other words, how would I detect that the object's status has changed?

Comment: What's? What do you want? Describe more details.

Comment: You need to be more precise. What are you doing ? What is a player ? What is a field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using [EventBus library.](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) When something changes, whatever that is, just `post` your own custom `SomethingChangedEvent`. All you need to do is to provide a method with `@Subscribe` annotation to listen for that Event:

```
@Subscribe
public void onSomethingChangedEvent(SomethingChangedEvent event){
     updateTextViews();  
     //Do whatever you wish here
}
```

As far as using the EventBus goes, just read their docs, they're great and it's quite easy to start using it.

Comment: Please keep Java naming conventions in your examples. Classes are upper-case, methods are lower-case.

Comment: Thanks, I know that, I put U as upper-case cause the method he used in question was also like that. Trust me, It pisses me off to see bad naming conventions.